# Video tag click event(play, stop, pause, etc...) tracking with Google Tag Manager

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I would like to know how to track click event of HTML 5 video tag with Google Tag Manager(GTM).

I have no access to GTM's admin page, i was wondering if there are any ways to tell GTM via JavaScript.

I thought a code for Google Analytics will do the work, but it didn't.

```
// just get one click event at a page load.
var isVideoPlayed = false; 
$('#myvideo').on('play', function(){
    if(!isVideoPlayed) {
         ga('send', 'event', 'Videos', 'play', 'My Video');
         isVideoPlayed = !isVideoPlayed;
    }
    return false;
});
```

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the code `ga('send', 'event', 'Videos', 'play', 'My Video');` is that it lacks the name of the GTM tracker, which is assigned when the tracking object is created through GTM. You could write a function that includes something like this:

```
ga.getAll()[0].get('name');
```

that would return the GTM tracker name. You would then be able to call your GA commands with the specific tracker name, like this:

```
ga('trackerName.send', 'event', 'Videos', 'play', 'My Video');
```

where `trackerName` is the name returned from aforementioned function.

Answer (score 0):

Google fully supports using javascript for its Analytics API using `analytics.js`.

> The analytics.js library is a JavaScript library for measuring how users interact with your website.

Start using it [on this page](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/).

For Google Tag Manager (GTM), Use the instructions on [this site](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/devguide).